# Alternate to gantt chart

Tags: usability, charts, timeline, multiple-data

I want to display two different tasks in my page. Type of the task will be two but number of tasks may vary up to 100 tasks. Very important thing is, all the tasks will fall under the timescale and there are connection (may be linking lines) between the tasks which shows the dependency between the tasks.

For this requirement, i have chosen to go with Gantt chart representation. And i choose the framework called "AngularGantt" https://www.angular-gantt.com/demo/

But after implementing with the real data(with 60 tasks), i found difficulties to visualize all. it has lots of linkage line here & there...

[image]

So suggest me,can i try something out of box solution... ?? or

Can i go with gantt?? If you have any ideas please let me know. And once again the requirements are,

1. need to display two different tasks with respect to the time
2. Task count may vary till 100
3. tasks will have dependency(connection) between each
4. No need of device compatible, PC is enough

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you show an image of what you have so far?

Comment: From your description, it seems like dependencies is what's causing your chart to look confusing. Can you tell us more about the kind of linkages between your tasks? Do you need to support multiple type of dependencies: Finish - Start, Start - Start, Finish - Finish, Start - Finish ? The more complex your dependency relationships, the more you should stick with a conventional display. In this case, a gantt view.

Comment: Hi @nightning...thank you.. i have updated the screen shot.. And as you rightly mentioned, i wanted display all the 4 dependencies (SS, SF, FS, & FF)

Answer (score 3):

Gantt charts do take a while getting used to, there's no doubt about it. Most of my experience with them has been with Microsoft Project, which is very good at what it does.

One of the things about gantt charts, though, is that they require a considerable amount of **upfront** planning. This kind of planning requires you to know the details of all tasks and subtasks involved in your project, how long they take, any dependencies, and so on. Because of this, they're not so ideal for projects that need to embrace flexibility. Projects in industries like software and design and marketing often involve after-the-fact changes and aren't as suited to using gantt charts.

**Excel**

I'm a huge MS Excel fan, so if I wanted to design something as an alternative to a Gantt chart, it'd probably be in Excel. One of the advantages of Excel would be that many people already have it installed, so if you need to share your info then they're less likely to have problems viewing it and probably won't need to learn a new tool (as they might with something like MS Project). So designing a spreadsheet to illustrate what it is you're doing is another option. I have seen different ways people have done this, ranging from a detailed 'task tracker' to a gantt chart lookalike.

**A combination**

Yet another option is to produce a combination of products to turn the project information into something that your project stakeholders can understand. So use things like flowcharts, charts/graphs, task lists, network diagrams, and so on to convey the information.

**Summary**

At the end of the day, what you use really depends on what you're trying to achieve. In most cases what project managers want to be able to do is to share information about their project in a way stakeholders can understand. If you're wanting to do the same thing, then use whatever works for you.

If you feel your project is complex enough to warrant a gantt chart, then persisting with it is well worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use several Gantt charts. One could show the general categories for tasks overall for the project. Then you could make individual Gantt charts for each category of tasks, those would be more loaded up with tasks. That might keep it easier to digest, understand, and use.

Comment: Thank you @Merrily.. That was a good idea... let me try..:)